# Implementing Lombok extensions for different environments once (javac, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, etc)

Tags: java, javac, apt, lombok

Recently I discovered Project Lombok that really looks very nice. I'd even say that it really covers a lot of boilerplates at compile time while I still write a sort of workarounds that help in runtime. I can't integrate Lombok to my current project because of lack of support in IntelliJ IDEA even for the basic support w/o Lombok extensions at all. I also discovered a nice and useful Lombok extension called *lombok-pg*, that features really cool stuff like `yield()` (no more consumer-producer threads). Having a little look at *lombok-pg* source code I noticed that it's written both for javac and Eclipse. Both implementations seem to look very similar, but as far as I understand Lombok extension implementation activity, let's say, IntelliJ IDEA support would require another, the third, implementation of the same thing, and it doesn't sound pretty encouraging.

I'm just curious: is there any kind of a framework that provides some general interface to manage AST with implementations for different environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just curious: is there any kind of a framework that provides some general interface to manage AST with implementations for different environments?

There ist the [Lombok AST](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok.ast) project trying to achieve exactly this. However, this all is tricky and I don't know the exact status (I only know it's not dead, last commit two weeks ago). Besides the AST manipulation, there's some compiler specific hacking to be done, especially in Eclipse, which makes it all pretty complicated.

Basically, Lombok runs in Intellij IDEA via a [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/lombok-intellij-plugin). As the Lombok authors themselves don't use Intellij, the development has a lower priority AFAICT.

Lombok-pg is cool, but no longer maintained. Porting it into Lombok is [not trivial](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/w5eYLEY9yBk/PYyO_tib5A4J).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. If I'm right, I tried to use that plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, and it seemed to lack a lot of Lombok built-in features, so it was just a rejected try to introduce Lombok to the project that's being written in IDEA. Frankly speaking, I didn't take a look into main Lombok source code, but I did _believe_ that Lombok has something like Lombok AST out of box (well, it makes sense), and as far as I understand now: it has not, unfortunately. So Lombok seems to bypass my project.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv: I unfortunately don't know more than I wrote. I sort of recall a thread discussing how Lombok uses Lombok AST (or not), but I can't find it anymore. Maybe try the [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/project-lombok) as I don't know how often the authors visit SO.

Comment: Recently there has been a lot of activity on the IntelliJ front. The plugin code has been cleaned up and a lot if the new Lombok features are being implemented. DisclosureL I am one of the Project Lombok developers (not the IntelliJ plugin)

Comment: Is [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/project-lombok/51qGiJ9Lpaw/D1nQCidG_EUJ) the thread you were talking about? It discusses Lombok **not** using Lombok AST. I can't find anything more recent.

Comment: @willkil: I'm afraid, yes. Actually, I meant the whole group. Anyway, there are (at least partly) the same people behind it, so ask there, they'll now more than I do.